# Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown Reason

Tags: mysql, macos, liquibase

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException error, when trying to run against my prod database.  Works fine against my test database.

I upgraded to 3.3.5, still same issue.

Any pointers?

Debug output below.

---

```
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Connected to *******@******@jdbc:mysql://**********.hostedresource.com:3306/******
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1433333922425 as 4718a9188c6a346602e81ac36af75247
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from skidreamzprd.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT LOCKED FROM skidreamzprd.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Lock Database
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE skidreamzprd.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'fe80:0:0:0:604c:c4ff:fe02:18f3%awdl0 (fe80:0:0:0:604c:c4ff:fe02:18f3%awdl0)', LOCKGRANTED = '2015-06-03 22:18:42.983' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0
INFO 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Resolving XML entity name='null', publicId='null', baseURI='null', systemId='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd'
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Found namespace details class liquibase.parser.core.xml.StandardNamespaceDetails for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Local path for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd is liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Successfully loaded XSD from liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Resolving XML entity name='null', publicId='null', baseURI='null', systemId='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd'
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Found namespace details class liquibase.parser.core.xml.StandardNamespaceDetails for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Local path for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd is liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Successfully loaded XSD from liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Resolving XML entity name='null', publicId='null', baseURI='null', systemId='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd'
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Found namespace details class liquibase.parser.core.xml.StandardNamespaceDetails for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Local path for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd is liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Successfully loaded XSD from liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Resolving XML entity name='null', publicId='null', baseURI='null', systemId='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd'
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Found namespace details class liquibase.parser.core.xml.StandardNamespaceDetails for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Local path for http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd is liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Successfully loaded XSD from liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Release Database Lock
DEBUG 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE skidreamzprd.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
INFO 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown Reason

SEVERE 3/06/15 10:18 PM: liquibase: Unknown Reason
java.lang.NullPointerException
at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:103)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:786)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:194)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1044)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:175)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94)


For more information, use the --logLevel flag
```

Comment: A pointer might be that the `DATABASECHANGELOG` is not available on your production DB. Can you asure that it is there and the user that liquibase uses to connect to the Prod DB has access to the table?

Comment: DATABASECHANGELOG is available.  I have just been experimenting, if I remove DATABASECHANGELOG it will run an update on the database, and a new DATABASECHANGELOG table is created.  If I then rerun after the first run, now with a DATABASECHANGELOG table, the null pointer error is thrown.

Comment: I just checked privileges.  Both my test server and prod server have the same privileges

GRANT USAGE ON *.*
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE

Comment: hm... Looking at the sources at (`3.3.x` branch) for [`StandardChangeLogHistoryService`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.3.x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/changelog/StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java) on line 103 it says: `Integer columnSize = changeLogTable.getColumn("LIQUIBASE").getType().getColumnSize();` I'd guess the `getColumn()` call returns `null`. Is the column `LIQUIBASE` in your `databasechangelog` table? You said you upgraded liquibase. Maybe an old version of liquibase did not have this col? (just guessing)

Comment: Both test and prod have the column LIQUIBASE.  The values in that column are currently 3.3.2, which I think was the first build I was running from.  They column definition row is LIQUIBASE, varchar(20), latin1_swedish_ci, ,Yes, NULL for Field,Type, Collation, Attributes, Null, Default.  Setup of this is same on both test and prod.  Perhaps the mysql version has some difference: test: 5.0.96-log V prod: 5.5.43-37.2-log.

Comment: If the line is correct (it should be) then there are only three objects where the `NPE` could happen. The `changeLogTable`, the `getColumn("LIQUIBASE")` or the `getType()`. I would exclude the `getType()`. Knowing that the first version of liquibase you used is 3.3.2. I would also exclude the `getColumn("LIQUIBASE")`. That leaves the `changeLogTable`. So my guess/pointer would still be that there is something setup differently. Did you put the liquibase tables in a different schema maybe?

Comment: @Jens - thanks for your input.  I was able to reproduce the bug in the 2nd comment above where I ran an update successively. The first time it was successful as there was no DATABASECHANGELOG table.  The first execution created that table and included the change sets.  The second time threw the exception, as there is something it doesn't like now that the table exists.  I assume it created the table in the expected format, maybe it is more a db server config issue perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a java developer, would it be difficult for me to modify the source, add some other diagnostics around the object call in question, recompile and run?  I know how to code, just not so familiar with the java build process.  Perhaps that would help reveal the operating context a little better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79762/discussion-between-jens-and-user3369864).

Answer (score 4):

With help from @Jens, we tracked this exception was caused by a broken VIEW in the prod db.  Nothing to do with the DATABASECHANGELOG.  Repairing the view then allowed liquibase to run as normal.  In this situation liquibase is susceptible to stability of the existing application database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late for an answer, but we ran into the same problem here. The reason was, as we've figured out, that we've updated our MySQL instance from 5.6.2x to 5.6.7x, and since then table and column names were not handled case insensitive anymore. In class [StandardChangeLogHistoryService](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.3.x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/changelog/StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java) liquibase tries to fetch column "LIQUIBASE" (in upper-case letters) from the DATABASECHANGELOG table, and fails. Although it's not a perfect solution, we solved the problem by recreating the specific database after making sure that property `--lower-case-table-names=1` is set in `my.cnf`.